# ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, sql, ubuntu, sql-server

у меня есть shared база данных mssql. когда подключаюсь к ней запуская код в VS все работает. однако проблема в том, что мне нужно запустить его на веб-сервере с ubuntu. и при запуске выдает ошибку "ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

```
import pyodbc

cnxn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
            "Server=xxxxxx,xxxxx;"
            "Database=xxxxx;"
            "UID=xxxxxx;"
            "PWD=xxxxxxxxx;")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
        INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, price)
        VALUES
            (1,'Desktop Computer',800),
            (2,'Laptop',1200),
            (3,'Tablet',200),
            (4,'Monitor',350),
            (5,'Printer',150)
                ''')
cnxn.commit()
```

пользуюсь хостингом поэтому напрямую с сервером взаимодействовать не могу

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. использовал pymssql, вместо pyodbc.